# Problema al plotear datos

Tags: python

la cuestión es que tengo el siguiente código en python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

data = np.loadtxt('Output/015_Termal/Estructura_termal:lon-lat-Q-sigma-area-Z-Tz')
lon = -6.8000e+01
lat = -2.5000e+01
Tz = data[np.where((data[:,1]==lat) & (data[:,0]==lon)),6]
Z = data[np.where((data[:,1]==lat) & (data[:,0]==lon)),5]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(Tz, Z, 'r')
plt.show()
```

El problema es que al momento de plotear, sólo genera los ejes pero no la curva que se debería formar con los datos de Tz y Z. Ya he revisado que ambas variables tengan datos y realmente no sé a que se puede deber.

Dejo un print de Tz y Z:

Tz:

```
[[    0.       35.472    70.033   103.73    136.6     168.68    200.03
230.66    260.62    289.95    318.66    346.8     374.39    401.45
428.02    454.12    479.77    504.99    529.8     554.24    578.3
602.02    625.4     648.47    671.25    693.73    715.95    737.91
759.63    781.11    802.37    823.43    844.28    864.94    885.43
905.74    925.89    945.88    965.73    985.44   1005.     1024.5
1043.8    1063.     1082.1    1101.1    1120.     1138.8    1157.5
1176.2    1194.7    1213.2    1231.6    1250.     1268.2    1286.5
1304.6    1322.7    1340.7    1358.7    1376.7    1394.6    1412.4
1430.2    1448.     1465.8    1483.5    1501.1    1518.8    1536.4
1553.9  ]]
```

Z:

```
[[  5.   4.   3.   2.   1.   0.  -1.  -2.  -3.  -4.  -5.  -6.  -7.  -8.
-9. -10. -11. -12. -13. -14. -15. -16. -17. -18. -19. -20. -21. -22.
-23. -24. -25. -26. -27. -28. -29. -30. -31. -32. -33. -34. -35. -36.
-37. -38. -39. -40. -41. -42. -43. -44. -45. -46. -47. -48. -49. -50.
-51. -52. -53. -54. -55. -56. -57. -58. -59. -60. -61. -62. -63. -64.
-65.]]
```

Comment: Hola, deje un print de ambas variables y no, no me arroja ningun warning o error.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tienes al parecer dos arrays de **dos dimensiones** y es eso lo que graficas. En realidad dibujas los puntos,  podemos hacer que muestre cada punto usando el argumento `marker` para ver lo que está pasando:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

Tz = np.array([[0.,        35.472,    70.033,    103.73,     136.6,      168.68,
                200.03,    230.66,    260.62,    289.95,     318.66,     346.8,
                374.39,    401.45,    428.02,    454.12,     479.77,     504.99,
                529.8,     554.24,    578.3,     602.02,     625.4,      648.47, 
                671.25,    693.73,    715.95,    737.91,     759.63,     781.11, 
                802.37,    823.43,    844.28,    864.94,     885.43,     905.74,
                925.89,    945.88,    965.73,    985.44,     1005.,      1024.5, 
                1043.8,    1063.,     1082.1,    1101.1,     1120.,      1138.8,
                1157.5,    1176.2,    1194.7,    1213.2,     1231.6,     1250., 
                1268.2,    1286.5,    1304.6,    1322.7,     1340.7,     1358.7, 
                1376.7,    1394.6,    1412.4,    1430.2,     1448.,      1465.8,
                1483.5,    1501.1,    1518.8,    1536.4, 
                1553.9,   ]])

Z = np.array([[5.,    4.,    3.,    2.,    1.,    0.,   -1.,   -2.,   -3.,   -4.,
              -5.,   -6.,   -7.,   -8.,   -9.,  -10.,   -11.,  -12.,  -13.,  -14.,
              -15.,  -16.,  -17.,  -18.,  -19.,  -20.,  -21.,  -22.,  -23.,  -24.,
              -25.,  -26.,  -27.,  -28.,  -29.,  -30.,  -31.,  -32.,  -33.,  -34.,
              -35.,  -36.,  -37.,  -38.,  -39.,  -40.,  -41.,  -42.,  -43.,  -44.,
              -45.,  -46.,  -47.,  -48.,  -49.,  -50.,  -51.,  -52.,  -53.,  -54.,
              -55.,  -56.,  -57.,  -58.,  -59.,  -60.,  -61.,  -62.,  -63.,  -64., 
              -65., ]])

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(Tz, Z, marker='o', color = 'r')

plt.show()
```

Lo cual nos muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar la curva puedes simplemente proporcionar dos arrays unidimensionales indexando:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(Tz[0], Z[0], color = 'r')

plt.show()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: perfecto! muchas gracias! funciono perfecto